# SQL Server - convert a column of comma-separated string to JSON array into a new column

Tags: arrays, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a SQL Server database with a column called `Categories` containing comma-separated values in the format `nvarchar(50)`. The length of each column is variable from record to record.

I've created a new empty column called `CategoriesJSONArray`. For all existing records, I need to convert the values in `Categories` to JSON arrays and write those converted values to `CategoriesJSONArray`.

How would I accomplish this using T-SQL, or from within the SSMS UI?

EDIT: example, as requested

Current:

```
Record   Categories

1        Sales, Support, Growth
2        Sales, Growth
3        Sales
4        Support, Growth, Sustain
```

Desired:

```
Record   Categories                  CategoriesJSONArray

1        Sales, Support, Growth      { "Sales" : "Support" : "Growth"}
2        Sales, Growth               { "Sales" : "Growth"}
3        Sales                       { "Sales" }
4        Support, Growth, Sustain    { "Sales" : "Growth" : "Sustain"}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a stored procedure to split the column based on the `,` and return it as a table.

Comment: This a good suggestion, let me look into this approach.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: The root of the issue is that you are storing delimited values in a single tuple. This violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of anguish. You will have to split those values first into a table. Here is an article with a number of excellent solutions to this problem. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @JohnCappelletti question updated with example.

Comment: Any of the splitters found on the link I posted can do this quite easily.

Comment: Just saying... your desired results is not valid JSON string

Comment: @SeanLange great I will look at this now.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti ok noted and agreed.  Thanks.  I think the solution below will allow me to adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There's some ways to split a delimited string into records and then aggregate those back into JSON, but I think some concatenation and replacing would be a easier here:

```
SELECT record,
    Categories,
    '{"' + REPLACE(Categories, ', ', '":"') + '"}' as CategoriesJSONArray
FROM table
```

That may need some tweaking to deal with spaces and whatnot and it obviously won't work if your JSON becomes more complex, but it's quick and dirty.

Comment: Beat me by seconds

Comment: I saw that, but yours was prettier! I'm glad that I am in good company with the solution though, I thought for sure it was too quick and dirty for SO with all the fancy strtok procedures and json-erizing that could be done.

Comment: I just added a space after the comma in the string literal. I think that ought to get rid of those.

Comment: @JNevill definitely makes sense, thanks!  I'll test it out now and assuming all goes well I'll mark yours as the answer.